# Nativescript fonticon package strange characters

Tags: angular, mobile, nativescript

I am using this 
https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ng2-fonticon
which is great for FontAwesome.

But I would like to extend my icon fonts with a custom set made by Icomoon.
So I generate my icomoon.ttf and its css with Icomoon webapp and prepared the font file and the css, just like FontAwesome.

Furthermore I extend the code with im class in css:

```
 .im { font-family: icomoon, icomoon; }
```

and

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: TNSFontIconService,
      useFactory: () => {
        return new TNSFontIconService({
          'fa': 'font-awesome.css',
          'im': 'icomoon.css'
        });
      }
    }
  ],
```

So FontAwesome is great, but my custom set is not.

This how I am trying:

```
  <Label class="fa" [text]="'fa-check-circle' | fonticon"></Label>
  <Label class="im" [text]="'im-settings' | fonticon"></Label>
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

Where is my settings icon, and what is this chinese-like character? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that it was a bug in the plugin. It handled only unicodes start with F (just like FontAwesome), meanwhile Icomoon generated unicodes started with E by default.

Now the bug is fixed.